# How do i set url for deployment on heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am working on node application.I have created successfully api and its working fine on localhost

```
http://localhost:3000/api/login
```

when i am going to deploy this app on heroku how would I change this link to one which herouku uses??

Comment: `encodeURI("<your_heroku_link>"+":"+process.env.PORT+"/api/login");`

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is PaaS (Platform as s Service) so it's include(and manage) a VM (Virtual Machine) for you.
By default Heroku gives youר application a default domain: `[name of app].herokuapp.com`, if you want set you own domain look [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) for more info.

Comment: I want it uses my localhost if i uses my localhost and it uses heroku when it is on server.

Comment: so define environment variable on each platform: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars